# Lumen slow response

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Looks like i am getting a big difference on the following test

```
$app->get('/', function () {
    return ['test' => 1];
});
```

This takes about 450ms and returns {'test': 1}

The following

```
$app->get('/', function () {
    echo json_encode['test' => 1];
    exit;
});
```

This takes about 170ms which is a big difference especially when you have a lot of requests to your api.

So probably something heavy happens in the response factory but i could not find it nor i could find a way to overwrite it with my own method. Any ideas?

Thanks

**Update**

Looks like the following line in Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation its adding 250 extra ms. Not sure why right now.

```
header(sprintf('HTTP/%s %s %s', $this->version, $this->statusCode, $this->statusText), true, $this->statusCode);
```

Which outputs

```
header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK1200');
```

Comment: Maybe try profiling with Xhprof, Blackfire.io or something else? Certainly seems like an interesting case.

Comment: What is the performance like with doing it the way its suggested in the documentation? https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#json-responses

Comment: It looks like the following line: header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK1200'); in Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation is causing the extra 250ms. So i guess its not related to lumen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the following line: `header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK1200');` in `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation` is causing the extra 250ms. So I guess its not related to lumen

Comment: How can we disable this?